# How to arrange three linearlayouts?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have four LinearLayouts, top one as a wrapper, the rest containing objects.  I'd like the center one (with the ListView) to fill my screen.  So, I should see button1, then the List of items that's scrollable, and then button2 at the bottom of the screen.

If I try setting the layout_height property of either the LinearLayout or ListView, I lose button2.

Maybe, I shouldn't even be using LinearLayouts?  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!  My layout XML is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"></Button>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" />

<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not try getting rid of your linear layouts that wrap each item, and set your outermost LinearLayout to android:orientation="vertical"? That way everything will be stacked as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Change your linearLayout3 to this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1.0">
   <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Basically set the layoutHeight to 'match_parent', and add 'layout_weight' to '1.0'.

Comment: this will remove all the elements below this LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout        

         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    

         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
         android:orientation="vertical"> 

    <Button android:text="Button"
          android:id="@+id/button1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

       <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

       <Button android:text="Button" 
               android:id="@+id/button2"         
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
               android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

          </LinearLayout>
```

do it in this way....